# Can we set "Do Not Forward" permission to an email sent programmatically?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail

I want to set "Do Not Forward" permission which is available on the Outlook Client, to the mails i sent programmatically. How can it be achieved?

I have a C# application which will sent a mail which contains sensitive information so would like to set this permission to all mails. I was not able to find solution for this.