# How to send an email with "do not forward" permission

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-online

In my organization we are authorized to use Graph API to send and receive emails programmatically through Shared Mailboxes hosted in Exchange Online.
I have a new requirement for a custom application to send emails that cannot be forwarded to anyone else. This is similar to Outlook's **Do not Forward** permission settings.
Is there any way we can achieve this using Graph API?

I tried looking into **sensitivityLabels** but that isn't available in the Microsoft.Graph or Microsoft Graph Beta libraries.
I understand that in Graph API framework the encryption is not available.

I see a duplicate question in SO but that one still doesn't have any response [Can we set "Do Not Forward" permission to an email sent programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792322/can-we-set-do-not-forward-permission-to-an-email-sent-programmatically)